# JQuery finding and add class to element

Tags: jquery

How do I add class to the span element?

For instant `class="fa fa-close"`

I need to do it with jQuery- finding the "sec" by id (i.e: `id="sec2"`) and then by attribute (i.e: `data-id="attrac-24"`)

HTML example:

```
<div class="well dropZone" id="sec2">

    <div class="panel panel-info attrac ui-widget-content" data-id="attrac-24" >
        <div class="panel-heading"><?PHP echo mb_substr ($attracIndex['title'], 0, 45, "utf-8") ?> <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa"></i></span></div>
        <div class="panel-body"><?PHP echo mb_substr ($attracIndex['des'], 0, 120, "utf-8")?></div>
    </div>                                  

</div>

<div class="well dropZone" id="sec3">

    <div class="panel panel-info attrac ui-widget-content" data-id="attrac-24" >
        <div class="panel-heading"><?PHP echo mb_substr ($attracIndex['title'], 0, 45, "utf-8") ?> <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa"></i></span></div>
        <div class="panel-body"><?PHP echo mb_substr ($attracIndex['des'], 0, 120, "utf-8")?></div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-info attrac ui-widget-content" data-id="attrac-35" >
        <div class="panel-heading"><?PHP echo mb_substr ($attracIndex['title'], 0, 45, "utf-8") ?> <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa"></i></span></div>
        <div class="panel-body"><?PHP echo mb_substr ($attracIndex['des'], 0, 120, "utf-8")?></div>
    </div>      

</div>
```

JQUERY

```
var secID = event.target.id;
var attacID = ui.item.data('id');
```

I  tried this:

```
$("#"+secID + " [data-id='"+attacID+"']" ).find("fa").addClass("fa-close");
```

Comment: Technically you do not need to do the id lookup part.  Since the element that you are after is a child of the event.target, you can just find the children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector is correct but `.find("fa")` is wrong. `fa` is a class so it should be `.find(".fa")`
Try this:

```
$("#"+secID + " [data-id='"+attacID+"']" ).find(".fa").addClass("fa-close");
```

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/leonardo9717/xpvt214o/262447/